# Does Play come with a default database

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to create my first project using Play.

I can see that in `application.conf` there is a some database configuration code.

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.username=sa
# db.default.password=""
```

Does that mean by any chance that play comes with a prepackages database, as Rails comes with SQLite?

In the introduction to Play from here https://www.playframework.com/, he doesn't write any code for adding a database.

What is the above code useful for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just an example of how to configure a DB connection.

The default application is using a memory database as SQLite, but in this case it is used [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).
If you check the file `build.sbt` you will find the dependency for this DB. But you can define any other database you may need here.

e.g.: If you need to connect to a postgreSQL DB you could use the example you may find [in this link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDatabase#PostgreSQL-database-engine-connection-properties):

```
db.customers.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.customers.url="jdbc:postgresql://database.example.com/playdb"
```

But you will have to define the dependency in `build.sbt`. [Something like](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1200-jdbc41):

`libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41`

Answer (score 3):

When you add the [`jdbc`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDatabase) library dependency to your Play project, that will also add the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), which is somewhat like the Java-based equivalent to SQLite in the Rails context, in that it's typically used locally with in-memory or file-based databases during development (not that you can't use it in production also.) In particular it's quite common to test using an in-memory H2 database, even if you use PostgreSQL etc in production.

The example settings in Play's default `application.conf` are intended to get you started by providing the basic configuration for an in-memory H2 DB, namely which driver class JDBC should use (put on the classpath by Play) and the database connection URL.